# java regex compile and matcher symbol not found error

Tags: java, regex

> i am trying to solve project euler #26 and i am using regex to solve
>   the problem but when compiling i am getting method not found error

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Pattern {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int count = 0;
        String regex = "(//d+?)//1)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex); //cannot find symbol compile
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("1");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(i);
            String elem = b.divide(b1, 15, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString();
            Matcher match = p.matcher(elem); //cannot find symbol matcher
            while (match.find()) {
                int x = match.start() - match.end();
                if (x > count)
                    count = x;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("the highest count is" + count);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Other than the typo pointed out in the answer by @Peter777 your [code is working without error](http://rextester.com/UAD40418).  I don't think you are actually seeing the error you posted in your question.  Perhaps that was generated by previous code.

Comment: `import java.lang.*;` - not needed

Comment: @ScaryWombat Compiles, but won't run, due to a typo: `String regex="(//d+?)//1)";`

Comment: You want us to spend our time to help you solve ýour programming contest entry (strange idea by the way). So you please spend the 1 minute it takes to properly indent/format your code!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple problems:

1. Your regexp is wrong as @Peter777 pointed out
2. Your class is named `Pattern`, same as `java.util.regex.Pattern`, this causes the compiler to try and use the compile method on your class instead of the `java.util.regex` one.

To try and solve the problem, fix the regex and rename your class to something else (or import the `java.util.regex` one with an alias).

Answer (score 1):

`String regex="(//d+?)//1)";`
This regex is for sure incorrect. You have two closing `)` and only one `(`

Also make sure your Pattern class is imported from `java.util.Regex` package.

Comment: But would not cause the compile problem that the OP is trying to initially fix

Comment: @ScaryWombat Fixing this typo gets the code running, not sure if the program is actually working.

Comment: *make sure your Pattern class is imported from* - which it is not because the class is named `Pattern`

Comment: What are you trying to prove here @ScaryWombat? If he takes a look at his imports then he'll find out, won't he?

Comment: oops I have *pissed off Peter* - sorry.  No but looking at he imports it *looks* ok, but he is not using `java.util.Regex.Pattern` he is using the class that he is writing now which is called `Pattern` and his class does not have a method called `compile` hence the compile error

Comment: Yes of course, still I don't understand how my answer is wrong in any matter. I pointed his typo and gave a clue about importing from correct package. Btw, you can not piss me off :) Have a good day @ScaryWombat

Comment: Sorry I did not mean to infer that your answer was wrong.  *Btw, you can not piss me off :)* I am not going to take this as a challenge